# Flask remove session variable from thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, flask

I try to implement a voting system. It works like this. If a user votes a post I record its temporary state in a session variable: upvoted, starred etc..

If current user hasn't voted before I save the results to temporary table. User may change the vote in 5 minutes. After 5 minutes pass the results are written to the database permanently using a thread.

I'd like to clear temporary session variables after results are written to database. Is there a way to achieve this?

task.py

```
import threading
import time
from flask import Flask, copy_current_request_context, session
from threading import Lock
from vote import voteQuestion

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key="appkey"

@app.before_first_request
def initializeTask():
    @copy_current_request_context
    def runTask():
        while True:
            voteQuestion()
            time.sleep(10)

    task = threading.Thread(target=runTask)
    task.start()

@app.route('/vote')
def vote():
    session['test'] = "This is a test"
    return 'success'


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello world!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

vote.py

```
from flask import session

def voteQuestion():
    print('session variables', session.items())
    result = session.get('test', 'not set')

    print ('result ', result)


    if 'test' in session:
        session.pop('test', None)
    print ('Running in the background')
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. The request is over, the session in that thread is essentially a read-only copy. Writing to it won't do anything because there's no response to carry the updated cookie to the browser.

It would make more sense to store the timestamp in the temporary table when you store the temporary vote, rather than trying to do something with threads and the session.